# BigQuery API query job return 404 for existing dataset, while using the magic request bigquery?

Tags: authentication, google-bigquery, google-colaboratory, http-status-code-404

I have set up a bigquery client with complete authentication, then tried to fetch the dataframe using a magic request

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
print('Authenticated')

%%bigquery df
select * from `project_id.dataset.table`
```

I'm getting the following error

```
The requested URL <code>/bigquery/v2/projects//jobs?prettyPrint=false</code> was not found on this server.
```

Can anyone tell me what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here I have not provided the complete details, hence it's unable to reach out to the page.

Provide the Project_id and project_details

```
pid = "Project_id"

%%bigquery --project $pid df
select * from `project_id.dataset.table`
```

This will work.